# Rails 3. Creating an API with Oauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently thinking of developing an API in Rails 3 using Oauth2 as authorization for developers. Do any of you guys know of a gem that can handle the authentication and authorization for the API? Perhaps a guide for Rails 3 somewhere?

Thankful for all input!

Answer (score 0):

I think this *might* help, however, I'm not sure if that's what you were looking for.

https://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin/tree/rails3

Comment: I am looking for a way for developers to authenicate with my API. Just like Twitter is doing. Would like to do this via OAuth2.

Answer (score 0):

oauth-plugin for Rails 3 should now allow you do create an OAuth 2 as well as OAuth 1a provider.

Alternatively, for OAuth 2 only, you could use the Thoughtworks [oauth2 provider](https://github.com/ThoughtWorksStudios/oauth2_provider).

Answer (score 0):

I think doorkeeper gem will help u.

https://github.com/applicake/doorkeeper.git